# Difference between const std::array<T,N> and std::array<const T, N>

Tags: c++

Is there any practical difference between `std::array<const T, N>` and `const std::array<T, N>`?

It looks that non-const array holding const elements is still not able to be swapped; assignment operator is not working either.

When should I prefer one over the other one?

```cpp
#include <array>

std::array<const int, 5> array_of_const = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::array<const int, 5> array_of_const2 = {1,2,3,4,5};

const std::array<int, 5> const_array = {1,2,3,4,5};
const std::array<int, 5> const_array2 = {1,2,3,4,5};

int main()
{
    // Assignment doesn't work for either
    array_of_const = array_of_const2;
    const_array = const_array2;

    // Swapping doesn't work for either
    array_of_const.swap(array_of_const2);
    const_array.swap(const_array2);

    // Indexing...
    array_of_const[0] = 0;
    const_array[0] = 0;

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, I agree.  I can think of no good reason for these,

Comment: a lot of people seem to hate [language-lawyer] questions without clear practical significance.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `[language-lawyer]` is not added by OP actually

Comment: I don't see why this has many upvote. (the initial ones are mostly probably balance vote(which I think is bad) I guess)

Comment: @ildjarn what "huge, obvious practical differences"? I don't see any

Comment: The only things I can think of are (1) the implications of casting away `const`, and (2) `T` being a pointer type.

Comment: @wooc in ildjarn's defense it's not the *clearest* example. I initially thought it was pointing out a difference as well.

Comment: Consider expanding the example since it shows each type side by side per access: https://godbolt.org/z/WjovbcMsn

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Copies of `std::array<const T, N>` are still "logically const", whereas by default a copy of `const std::array<T, N>` is mutable. If allowing or preventing that matters to you, one is preferable to the other.

There are differences in what templates they match, e.g. the case in [Ilya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70803253/2610810).

Answer (score 22):

there could be at least one difference - case when you need to pass variable to some other function, for example:

```
#include <array>

std::array<const int, 5> cc_arr5 = {1,2,3,4,5};
const std::array<int, 5> cc_arr5_2 = {1,2,3,4,5};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
void func(std::array<T, N>& a) {
    // do not change a, for example just calculate sum
}

int main()
{
    func(cc_arr5);
    func(cc_arr5_2); // this line does not compile

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Well, a difference is a difference, even if it's contrived. Although we've all seen functions in the wild that take non-const references and then don't actually mutate the parameter, so I guess it's not that contrived.

Comment: Exactly the example I was about to post ... have some Unicorn points for being a few minutes faster than I am.

Comment: Consider expanding the example by showing that `a` needs to not be mutated in the function body for this to work? https://godbolt.org/z/qqPc9qW77

Comment: @JohnFilleau yep, added comment

Comment: Of course, passing a [`std::span`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) by value is much preferable to passing a `std::array` or native array by reference...

Comment: Now the only thing missing is an example for `const std:array<const int, 5>`.

Answer (score 9):

They are indeed different types, so you cannot use one in a place whether the other would be expected, for example in a function call or an assignment.

That being said, as an array is a fixed size container with no auxiliary data member, having the container const prevent any change to its elements and having the elements const does not allow any change to the container since it obviously has no other data member.

Said differently both types will have the very same valid and invalid operations.

The main difference I can think about, is the `const_cast` implication: an array can be (implicitly) converted to a const array of the same element type but not to an array of the const modified type:

```
std::array<int, 3> a {1, 2, 3};

std::array<const int, 3> b = a; // Error: no known conversion from 'array<int, [...]>' to 'const array<const int, [...]>
const std::array<int, 3> c = a; // Ok
```

Comment: Perhaps _two_ `const_cast` implications: One of the two types can also have `const` casted away.